# What are providers in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-providers

In the Angular2 component configuration `providers` is one of the keys that we could specify. How are these providers defined and what are they used for?

```
@Component({
  ..
  providers: [..],
  ..
})
```

**Note**:

Angular2 documentation is gradually maturing but still sparse. It currently defines **providers** as:

> An array of dependency injection providers for services that the
>   component requires.

This recursive definition isn't very helpful. A more detailed explanation with an example would really help.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Providers are usually singleton (one instance) objects, that other objects have access to through dependency injection (DI).

If you plan to use an object multiple times, for example, the `Http` service in different components, you can ask for the same instance of that service (reuse it). You do that with the help of DI by *providing* a reference to the same object that DI creates for you.

```
@Component){
  ..
  providers: [Http]
}
```

..instead of creating new object every time:

```
@Component){}
class Cmp {
  constructor() {
    // this is pseudo code, doens't work
    this.http = new Http(...options);
  }
}
```

This is an approximation, but that's the general idea behind [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) - let the framework handle creation and maintenance of reusable objects... *Provider* is Angular's term for these reusable objects (dependencies).

Answer (score 25):

**Register injectables**

Providers make injectables known to Angular's DI and define the scope of an injectable (service).

**Hierarchy of injectors**

Angular's DI creates a tree of injectors (parent > child > grandchild >...) that resembles the structure of your components and directives.

**Single instance per provider**

Providers are maintained per injector. Each provider provides a single instance of an injectable.

**Provider lookup**

When a component or directive has a dependency (constructor parameter), DI starts looking on this component's injector for providers. If it has one it requests the instance from this provider and injects it.

If the injector doesn't have a provider for the requested key (type) then the parent injector is visited, up to the root (bootstrap) until a provider is found and its instance can be injected. (If no provider is found DI throws an error).

**Define the scope of an injectable instance**

This way you can define the scope of a shared service, because DI starts looking from the component where an instance is requested upwards until it finds one.

**Singleton or not**

How many places you provide an injectable determines how many instances will be created (they are only instantiated if actually requested).

If you want a single instance for your whole application, then provide an injectable only **once** at the root component (or with `bootstrap(AppComponent, [...])` which results in the same behavior.

If you want a new instance for each component `A`, then add it to providers of the component `A`.

**(update) NgModule lazy and non-lazy**

With the introduction of `NgModule` modules, additional levels were introduced. Providers registered with non-lazy-loaded modules are above the root component in the hierarchy.

Lazy-loaded modules are above the components and directives loaded by these components.

Because providers are read-only after an injector is created, there is no way to add providers from lazy loaded modules to the root injector. Therefore, lazy loaded modules get their own root scope.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/45231440/217408

Comment: As always @Günter Zöchbauer You clarified it for me. Thank You.
I always follow your answers to angular js queries.

Answer (score 12):

Think of providers like a recipe that tells angular how to inject a service.

We often declare providers in angular this way:

```
providers: [AnyService]
```

This is just a short hand for this:

```
[new Provider(AnyService, {useClass: AnyService})]
```

Both approaches are saying: Whenever someone requires "AnyService", provide the class "AnyService"

See that even though I'm providing the same class in the example above, in another scenario I could do something like this.

```
[new Provider(AnyService, {useClass: AnyServiceCustom})]
```

But in both scenarios, constructor would remain the same:

```
constructor( private _anyService: AnyService) {
}
```

To understand it better you need to understand how dependency injection works in Angular 2 as providers are directly related to it.

This is a must-read for every angular 2 developer.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html?The%20Provider%20class%20and%20provide%20function#!#injector-providers

Answer (score 4):

Add @Sasxa words, I want to point to [Pro Angular book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DNRVMRN) by Adam Freeman (chapter 20 (Using Service Providers)) for better, clear and detailed  explanation with amazing examples.

**Providers** are classes that create and manage *service objects* the first time that Angular needs to resolve a dependency.**Providers** is used to register the classes to an angular module **as a service**.And then, this service classes can be used by other components during the itself creation phase in the module.

"*Services* are objects that provide common functionality to support other building blocks in an application, such as directives, components, and pipes. What’s important about services is the way that they are used, which is through a process called **dependency injection**. Using services can increase the flexibility and scalability of an Angular application, but dependency injection can be a difficult topic to understand." (Pro Angular (chapter 20))

Actually services can manage to distrubute objects as services using by dependency injection.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

export enum LogLevel {DEBUG, INFO, ERROR}

    @Injectable()
    export class LogService {
      minimumLevel: LogLevel = LogLevel.INFO;
      logInfoMessage(message: string){
       this.logMessage(LogLevel.INFO, message);
      }
    }
```

---

```
@Component({
     selector: "example",
     templateUrl: "example.component.html"
})
export class exampleComponent {

  constructor(logService: LogService) {};
  //to do impl
}
```

---

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  providers:    [ LogService ],
  declarations: [ ExampleComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Providers are just the instance of the service.**

You can create them once and use them everywhere or you can create multiple instances.

*Let's understand how do we use them in Angular*

All the services are registered with Angular but they can't be used until we instantiate them. So first, we have to instantiate the services and we do that by using providers.

There are two ways to instantiate the service. First by using *providers array* and the second one is to use *providedIn*.

The first method **Using Providers Array**

To use the service globally, we can place the providers in AppModule. By doing this, the instance of that service is created and all the components or other services in the app will use the same instance.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NewService } from './newService';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [NewService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

To use the service inside any specific component, we can place the providers in ComponentModule. By doing this, the new instance of that service is created and all the child components will use the same instance(It'll override the parent instance).

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NewService } from './newService';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  providers:[NewService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private newService: newService) { }

  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

**NOTE: If you place providers in AppComponent, then all the components in that app can use that instance but other services won't have access to that instance. To make other services also use the same instance, place it in AppModule.**

The second method using **providedIn**

You can use Injectable decorator to instantiate any service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root' | Type<any>
})
export class UserService {
}
```

If it is root, then the whole application has access to that service. It means Angular creates a single instance of that service and whole application uses the same instance.

If it has to be accessed in only specific module, we can do that by giving the module name for *providedIn*

```
@Injectable({
   providedIn: AnyModule
})
```

*One more advantage of using Injectable decorator to instantiate service is that, if the service is not at all used anywhere in that application, then it will not be there in compiled Angular Application.*

Answer (score -4):

```
import { service_name} from '../path';

@Component({

  selector: 'selector_name',     
  templateUrl: './html file name ',
  styleUrls: ['./css file name '],
  providers: [ ./'service_name'];

})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private Service_name: service_name) { 
    //enter code here
}
```